# Implement a code into a background to an existing site. (Replacing background image with JS animation)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, web

I am in need of help with my portfolio.
I have recently gained interests in Webdesign, so I started off learning basics from templates.
My question now is, since I cannot manage to get it to work, how could I implement this javascript into the background of my site, where there currently is that minecraft image being shown?

Whenever I try to implement it, I break the whole page for whatever reason, sadly.

Best regards!

The code I want to be implemented:
https://codepen.io/towc/pen/eNEBQX (code below)

html:

```
<canvas id=c></canvas>
<a href=http://hd4desktop.com/669-colours-circle-rainbow-hd-wallpaper/>
<img src=http://hd4desktop.com/images/m/a-colours-circle-rainbow-HDWallpaper.jpg ></a>
```

css:

```
body {

  overflow: hidden;
}
canvas {

  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: black;
}

a {

  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  left: calc( 100% - 200px );
  top: calc( 100% - 130px );
}
img {
  width: 200px;
}
```

JS:

```
// base image: http://hd4desktop.com/images/m/a-colours-circle-rainbow-HD-Wallpaper.jpg

var w = c.width = window.innerWidth,
    h = c.height = window.innerHeight,
    ctx = c.getContext( '2d' ),

    opts = {

      lineCount: 100,
      starCount: 30,

      radVel: .01,
      lineBaseVel: .1,
      lineAddedVel: .1,
      lineBaseLife: .4,
      lineAddedLife: .01,

      starBaseLife: 10,
      starAddedLife: 10,

      ellipseTilt: -.3,
      ellipseBaseRadius: .15,
      ellipseAddedRadius: .02,
      ellipseAxisMultiplierX: 2,
      ellipseAxisMultiplierY: 1,
      ellipseCX: w / 2,
      ellipseCY: h / 2,

      repaintAlpha: .015
    },
    gui = new dat.GUI,

    lines = [],
    stars = [],
    tick = 0,
    first = true;

function init() {

  lines.length = stars.length = 0;

  ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-over';
  ctx.fillStyle = '#333';
  ctx.fillRect( 0, 0, w, h );

  if( first ) {

    var f = gui.addFolder( 'logics' );
    f.add( opts, 'lineCount', 1, 300 );
    f.add( opts, 'starCount', 1, 300 );
    f.add( opts, 'radVel', 0, 1 );
    f.add( opts, 'lineBaseVel', .01, 1 );
    f.add( opts, 'lineAddedVel', 0, 1 );
    f.add( opts, 'lineBaseLife', 0, 1 );
    f.add( opts, 'lineAddedLife', 0, 1 );
    f.add( opts, 'starBaseLife', 0, 100 );
    f.add( opts, 'starAddedLife', 0, 100 );
       f = gui.addFolder( 'graphics' );
    f.add( opts, 'ellipseTilt', -Math.PI, Math.PI ).step( .1 );
    f.add( opts, 'ellipseBaseRadius', 0, .5 );
    f.add( opts, 'ellipseAddedRadius', 0, .5 );
    f.add( opts, 'ellipseAxisMultiplierX', 0, 3 );
    f.add( opts, 'ellipseAxisMultiplierY', 0, 3 );
    f.add( opts, 'ellipseCX', 0, w );
    f.add( opts, 'ellipseCY', 0, h );
    f.add( opts, 'repaintAlpha', 0, 1 );
    gui.add( window, 'init' ).name( 'reset animation' );
    gui.add( window, 'LuukLamers' );

    loop();
    first = false;
  }
}

function loop() {

  window.requestAnimationFrame( loop );
  step();
  draw();
}

function step() {

  tick += .5;

  if( lines.length < opts.lineCount && Math.random() < .5 )
    lines.push( new Line );

  if( stars.length < opts.starCount )
    stars.push( new Star );

  lines.map( function( line ) { line.step(); } );
  stars.map( function( star ) { star.step(); } );
}

function draw() {

  ctx.shadowBlur = 0;
  ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-over';
  ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(0,0,0,alp)'.replace( 'alp', opts.repaintAlpha );
  ctx.fillRect( 0, 0, w, h );

  ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'lighter';

  ctx.translate( opts.ellipseCX, opts.ellipseCY );
  ctx.rotate( opts.ellipseTilt );
  ctx.scale( opts.ellipseAxisMultiplierX, opts.ellipseAxisMultiplierY );

  // ctx.shadowBlur here almost does nothing
  lines.map( function( line ) { line.draw(); } );

  ctx.scale( 1/opts.ellipseAxisMultiplierX, 1/opts.ellipseAxisMultiplierY );
  ctx.rotate( -opts.ellipseTilt );
  ctx.translate( -opts.ellipseCX, -opts.ellipseCY );

  stars.map( function( star ) { star.draw(); } );
}

function Line() {

  this.reset();
}
Line.prototype.reset = function() { 

  this.rad = Math.random() * Math.PI * 2,
  this.len = w * ( opts.ellipseBaseRadius + Math.random() * opts.ellipseAddedRadius );
  this.lenVel = opts.lineBaseVel + Math.random() * opts.lineAddedVel;

  this.x = this.px = Math.cos( this.rad ) * this.len;
  this.y = this.py = Math.sin( this.rad ) * this.len;

  this.life = this.originalLife = w * ( opts.lineBaseLife + Math.random() * opts.lineAddedLife );

  this.alpha = .2 + Math.random() * .8;
}
Line.prototype.step = function() {

  --this.life;

  var ratio = 1 - .1 *  this.life / this.originalLife;

  this.px = this.x;
  this.py = this.y;

  this.rad += opts.radVel;
  this.len -= this.lenVel;

  this.x = Math.cos( this.rad ) * this.len;
  this.y = Math.sin( this.rad ) * this.len;

  if( this.life <= 0 )
    this.reset();
}
Line.prototype.draw = function() {

  var ratio = Math.abs( this.life / this.originalLife - 1/2 );

  ctx.lineWidth = ratio * 5;
  ctx.strokeStyle = ctx.shadowColor = 'hsla(hue, 80%, light%, alp)'
    .replace( 'hue', tick + this.x / ( w * ( opts.ellipseBaseRadius + opts.ellipseAddedRadius ) ) * 100 )
    .replace( 'light', 75 - ratio * 150 )
    .replace( 'alp', this.alpha );
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo( this.px, this.py );
  ctx.lineTo( this.x, this.y );

  ctx.stroke();
}

function Star() {

  this.reset();
};
Star.prototype.reset = function() {

  this.x = Math.random() * w;
  this.y = Math.random() * h;
  this.life = opts.starBaseLife + Math.random() * opts.starAddedLife;
}
Star.prototype.step = function() {

  --this.life;

  if( this.life <= 0 )
    this.reset();
}
Star.prototype.draw = function(){

  ctx.fillStyle = ctx.shadowColor = 'hsla(hue, 80%, 50%, .2)'
    .replace( 'hue', tick + this.x / w * 100 );
  ctx.shadowBlur = this.life;
  ctx.fillRect( this.x, this.y, 1, 1 );
};

window.addEventListener( 'resize', function() {

  w = c.width = window.innerWidth;
  h = c.height = window.innerHeight;

  opts.ellipseCX = w / 2;
  opts.ellipseCY = h / 2;

  init();
} );

function LuukLamers() {

  var i = 0,
      array = [ 300, 74, 0.04, 0.1, 0.1, .55, 10, 100, 10, -.15, .18, .01, 3, 1, w / 2, h / 2, 0.02 ];

  for( var key in opts ) {

    opts[ key ] = array[ i ];
    ++i;
  }

  init();
}

init();
```

My current site (THERE WILL BE MUSIC AUTOPLAY SO MUTE THE SITE!)
http://5.196.26.60/backgroundmusic.html

I think the basic css things would interfer with some of the other, already used ones?

If you need any else information, feel free to ask and I try to answer it!

Best regards and thanks for the help in advance!:).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure how close you got but what you basically need to do is to include all the css and javascript within your site. This includes the javascript GUI library that is being used to make the space effect. In the codepen, if you click on the little setting wheel beside JS you can see the libraries that are included. Make sure you have these added. After that I just added the html within the `overlay` div of your page. See below and hope it helps...

```js
var w = c.width = window.innerWidth,
    h = c.height = window.innerHeight,
    ctx = c.getContext( '2d' ),
    
    opts = {
      
      lineCount: 100,
      starCount: 30,
      
      radVel: .01,
      lineBaseVel: .1,
      lineAddedVel: .1,
      lineBaseLife: .4,
      lineAddedLife: .01,
      
      starBaseLife: 10,
      starAddedLife: 10,
      
      ellipseTilt: -.3,
      ellipseBaseRadius: .15,
      ellipseAddedRadius: .02,
      ellipseAxisMultiplierX: 2,
      ellipseAxisMultiplierY: 1,
      ellipseCX: w / 2,
      ellipseCY: h / 2,
      
      repaintAlpha: .015
    },
    gui = new dat.GUI,
    
    lines = [],
    stars = [],
    tick = 0,
    first = true;

function init() {
  
  lines.length = stars.length = 0;
  
  ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-over';
  ctx.fillStyle = '#333';
  ctx.fillRect( 0, 0, w, h );
  
  if( first ) {
    
    var f = gui.addFolder( 'logics' );
    f.add( opts, 'lineCount', 1, 300 );
    f.add( opts, 'starCount', 1, 300 );
    f.add( opts, 'radVel', 0, 1 );
    f.add( opts, 'lineBaseVel', .01, 1 );
    f.add( opts, 'lineAddedVel', 0, 1 );
    f.add( opts, 'lineBaseLife', 0, 1 );
    f.add( opts, 'lineAddedLife', 0, 1 );
    f.add( opts, 'starBaseLife', 0, 100 );
    f.add( opts, 'starAddedLife', 0, 100 );
       f = gui.addFolder( 'graphics' );
    f.add( opts, 'ellipseTilt', -Math.PI, Math.PI ).step( .1 );
    f.add( opts, 'ellipseBaseRadius', 0, .5 );
    f.add( opts, 'ellipseAddedRadius', 0, .5 );
    f.add( opts, 'ellipseAxisMultiplierX', 0, 3 );
    f.add( opts, 'ellipseAxisMultiplierY', 0, 3 );
    f.add( opts, 'ellipseCX', 0, w );
    f.add( opts, 'ellipseCY', 0, h );
    f.add( opts, 'repaintAlpha', 0, 1 );
    gui.add( window, 'init' ).name( 'reset animation' );
    gui.add( window, 'LuukLamers' );
    
    loop();
    first = false;
  }
}

function loop() {
  
  window.requestAnimationFrame( loop );
  step();
  draw();
}

function step() {
  
  tick += .5;
  
  if( lines.length < opts.lineCount && Math.random() < .5 )
    lines.push( new Line );
  
  if( stars.length < opts.starCount )
    stars.push( new Star );
  
  lines.map( function( line ) { line.step(); } );
  stars.map( function( star ) { star.step(); } );
}

function draw() {
  
  ctx.shadowBlur = 0;
  ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-over';
  ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(0,0,0,alp)'.replace( 'alp', opts.repaintAlpha );
  ctx.fillRect( 0, 0, w, h );
  
  ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'lighter';
  
  ctx.translate( opts.ellipseCX, opts.ellipseCY );
  ctx.rotate( opts.ellipseTilt );
  ctx.scale( opts.ellipseAxisMultiplierX, opts.ellipseAxisMultiplierY );
  
  // ctx.shadowBlur here almost does nothing
  lines.map( function( line ) { line.draw(); } );
  
  ctx.scale( 1/opts.ellipseAxisMultiplierX, 1/opts.ellipseAxisMultiplierY );
  ctx.rotate( -opts.ellipseTilt );
  ctx.translate( -opts.ellipseCX, -opts.ellipseCY );
  
  stars.map( function( star ) { star.draw(); } );
}

function Line() {
  
  this.reset();
}
Line.prototype.reset = function() { 

  this.rad = Math.random() * Math.PI * 2,
  this.len = w * ( opts.ellipseBaseRadius + Math.random() * opts.ellipseAddedRadius );
  this.lenVel = opts.lineBaseVel + Math.random() * opts.lineAddedVel;
  
  this.x = this.px = Math.cos( this.rad ) * this.len;
  this.y = this.py = Math.sin( this.rad ) * this.len;
  
  this.life = this.originalLife = w * ( opts.lineBaseLife + Math.random() * opts.lineAddedLife );
  
  this.alpha = .2 + Math.random() * .8;
}
Line.prototype.step = function() {
  
  --this.life;
  
  var ratio = 1 - .1 *  this.life / this.originalLife;
  
  this.px = this.x;
  this.py = this.y;
  
  this.rad += opts.radVel;
  this.len -= this.lenVel;
  
  this.x = Math.cos( this.rad ) * this.len;
  this.y = Math.sin( this.rad ) * this.len;
  
  if( this.life <= 0 )
    this.reset();
}
Line.prototype.draw = function() {
  
  var ratio = Math.abs( this.life / this.originalLife - 1/2 );
  
  ctx.lineWidth = ratio * 5;
  ctx.strokeStyle = ctx.shadowColor = 'hsla(hue, 80%, light%, alp)'
    .replace( 'hue', tick + this.x / ( w * ( opts.ellipseBaseRadius + opts.ellipseAddedRadius ) ) * 100 )
    .replace( 'light', 75 - ratio * 150 )
    .replace( 'alp', this.alpha );
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo( this.px, this.py );
  ctx.lineTo( this.x, this.y );
  
  ctx.stroke();
}

function Star() {
  
  this.reset();
};
Star.prototype.reset = function() {
  
  this.x = Math.random() * w;
  this.y = Math.random() * h;
  this.life = opts.starBaseLife + Math.random() * opts.starAddedLife;
}
Star.prototype.step = function() {
  
  --this.life;
  
  if( this.life <= 0 )
    this.reset();
}
Star.prototype.draw = function(){
  
  ctx.fillStyle = ctx.shadowColor = 'hsla(hue, 80%, 50%, .2)'
    .replace( 'hue', tick + this.x / w * 100 );
  ctx.shadowBlur = this.life;
  ctx.fillRect( this.x, this.y, 1, 1 );
};

window.addEventListener( 'resize', function() {
  
  w = c.width = window.innerWidth;
  h = c.height = window.innerHeight;
  
  opts.ellipseCX = w / 2;
  opts.ellipseCY = h / 2;
  
  init();
} );

function LuukLamers() {
  
  var i = 0,
      array = [ 300, 74, 0.04, 0.1, 0.1, .55, 10, 100, 10, -.15, .18, .01, 3, 1, w / 2, h / 2, 0.02 ];
  
  for( var key in opts ) {
    
    opts[ key ] = array[ i ];
    ++i;
  }
  
  init();
}

init();
```

```css
body {
  
  overflow: hidden;
}
canvas {
  
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: black;
}

a {
  
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  left: calc( 100% - 200px );
  top: calc( 100% - 130px );
}
img {
  width: 200px;
}
/*Add z-index to the controls */
.dg.ac {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 10;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Make sure you have this included -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dat-gui/0.5.1/dat.gui.min.js"></script> 

<section id="intro" style="background-image: url('http://pungaleet.bplaced.net/Portfolio/img/Testrender.jpg');" class="intro">      
      <div class="overlay">
  <canvas id=c></canvas>
  <a href=http://hd4desktop.com/669-colours-circle-rainbow-hd-wallpaper/><img src=http://hd4desktop.com/images/m/a-colours-circle-rainbow-HD-Wallpaper.jpg ></a>
   </div>
      <div class="content">
        <div class="container clearfix">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 col-sm-12">
              <p class="italic">Hey there, buddy!</p>
              <h1>Welcome to my newly created Portfolio!</h1>
              <p class="italic">Check it out to find out stuff about me and my Services like Minecraft coding,</p>
     <p></p>
     <p class="italic"> League of Legends coaching and much more.</p>
     <div id="navigation" class="">

       <div class="scroll-down">
    <h5>Scroll down to see more</h5>
    <a href="#about"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-down"></i></a>
    </div>
     
              
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Awesome, I got it kind of working for now, I will tweak some settings, thanks for the help! 
The only thing I see a problematic in there is that you cannot edit the settings on the top right corner now?

Best regards!
Preview to see how I did it:
http://5.196.26.60/almostdone/backgroundmusic.html

Comment: @Punga you just need to apply some z-index to the controls to get them above the overly .dg.ac { z-index: 10;}

Comment: Hello, may I ask where you added that thing to? Since what I have done is
I have added those lines beneath the thing you added in the html thing:
    
    <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dat-gui/0.5.1/dat.gui.min.js'></script>
   <script  src="js/index.js"></script>

aka I have added it beneath this line:
<a href=http://hd4desktop.com/669-colours-circle-rainbow-hd-wallpaper/><img src=http://hd4desktop.com/images/m/a-colours-circle-rainbow-HD-Wallpaper.jpg ></a>

Comment: Also I have noticed, that this bar follows my navbar through the whole page :/

Comment: @Punga You would normally add external resources like this within the <head></head> . May be put it just above the closing </head> tag.

Comment: @Punga give the controls a position absolute instead of a position of fixed it you want it to stay at the top of the page.

Comment: Ah I tried that and it adds then over the landing page, I guess I just try to remove those controls, I will inform you how I got it managed to work!:)

Comment: @Punga Well if you don't need them then that's probably what I would do too! :)

Comment: Hey, so I have added this 
    dat.GUI.toggleHide();
in the javascript beneath
    gui.add( window, 'LuukLamers' );

Comment: @Punga Looks good! you could probably have hidden it with css too using .dg.ac {display: none;}

Comment: @Punga if you're happy enough with my original answer anyway you might mark the question as answered. I'd appreciate it :)

Comment: I already searched for that option, and I now found it, done!:)

Comment: Woo! Thanks @Punga